# Strange behavior on Windows setting file creation time

Tags: c#, file

I have a strange behavior on Windows 10 Pro. I have written the following C# code, which seems to work for 2 seconds until the file (txt/pdf) changes back TO ITS ORIGINAL modification / creation time. Maybe someone can explain that to me?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = args[0];
            var dateTimeStr = args[1];

            try
            {
                DateTime dateTime;
                var isOK = DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeStr,out dateTime);
                if (!isOK)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("Could not parse date <{0}>! Try format <'2019-03-12 12:14:01 AM'> Exiting...", dateTimeStr));
                    return;
                }

                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("File <{0}> does not exist! Exiting...",fileInfo.FullName));
                    return;
                }
                
                Console.Write("Will set date <{0}> on file <{1}>. Continue [yY]?", fileInfo.FullName, dateTimeStr);
                var confirm = Console.ReadLine();
                if (confirm.ToLower().Contains("y"))
                {
                    // This does not work on the original file
                    File.SetLastAccessTime(fileInfo.FullName, dateTime);
                    File.SetCreationTime(fileInfo.FullName, dateTime);
                    File.SetLastWriteTime(fileInfo.FullName, dateTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Changed date to <{0}> on file <{1}>.", fileInfo.FullName, File.GetLastWriteTime(fileInfo.FullName));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aborted!");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for trying! Strange. It flips back after 2 seconds or so. The same behavior is observed with a tool to manipulate file attributes. It seems as if Windows has some kind of memory....I will try copying file and renaming later. And possibly also on a Linux box.

Comment: @mathtec Use `ProcMon` (in Microsoft Sysinternals Suite) to monitor filesystem activity to see exactly why the file dates are being reset. I'll bet your program is probably just fighting with OneDrive or DropBox or dodgy Anti-virus software.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are absolutely right! I am using Teamdrive! My solution was to copy the file, modify it and then wait for 10 Seconds and rename it back :-)

Comment: @mathtec You should file a bug report with TeamDrive as well then.

Answer (score 2):

(Converting my comment to an answer:)

[Use ProcMon, part of Microsoft Sysinternals, to monitor filesystem activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (and many other kinds of program activity) to see exactly why the file dates are being reset.

I'll bet your program is probably just fighting with poorly-written file/folder synchronization software, like OneDrive or DropBox or dodgy anti-virus software.